# Lerp rotation angles clock or counter-clockwise

Tags: algorithm, math, angle

I'm trying to find an implementation of angle lerp (linear interpolation) that allows you to specify direction (clock or counter-clockwise). Most implementations I found rely on the shortest path possible, for example:

https://gist.github.com/shaunlebron/8832585

I'd like to have a function like:

```
// from        = angle where to start
// to          = target angle
// direction   = wether to reach "to" clock or counter clock wise
// progress    = 0-1 progress range 0 = from value 1 = to value.

function angle_lerp(from, to, direction, progress) {}
```

Here are a couple of examples to further clarify the expected behavior of the function. All examples are based on a **0-360** degree range:

```
# clockwise (short path)
angle_lerp(from=350, to=10, direction=clockwise, progress=0) = 350
angle_lerp(from=350, to=10, direction=clockwise, progress=0.5) = 0
angle_lerp(from=350, to=10, direction=clockwise, progress=1) = 10

# counter-clockwise (long path)
angle_lerp(from=350, to=10, direction=counter, progress=0) = 350
angle_lerp(from=350, to=10, direction=counter, progress=0.5) = 180
angle_lerp(from=350, to=10, direction=counter, progress=1) = 10
```

```
# clockwise (short path)
angle_lerp(from=90, to=180, direction=clockwise, progress=0.33333) = 119.7
angle_lerp(from=90, to=180, direction=clockwise, progress=0.5) = 135
angle_lerp(from=90, to=180, direction=clockwise, progress=0.8) = 162 

# counter (long path)
angle_lerp(from=90, to=180, direction=counter, progress=0.33333) = 0
angle_lerp(from=90, to=180, direction=counter, progress=0.66666) = 270
```

example where **from** is "ahead" of **to**:

```
# clockwise (long path)
angle_lerp(from=45, to=0, direction=clockwise, progress=0.1) = 76.5
angle_lerp(from=45, to=0, direction=clockwise, progress=0.5) = 202.5
angle_lerp(from=45, to=0, direction=clockwise, progress=0.95) = 344.25

# counter (short route)
angle_lerp(from=45, to=0, direction=counter, progress=0.1) = 40.5
angle_lerp(from=45, to=0, direction=counter, progress=0.5) = 22.5
angle_lerp(from=45, to=0, direction=counter, progress=0.95) = 2.25
```

Comment: The language is not super important, hopefully the logic is simple and thereby easily ported to different context.

Comment: So angle_lerp(0, 2, counter, 0.5) is 1 or -1?

Comment: yes! i guess it depends on the range, so for example 0-360 range, and from=0, to=2, direction=counter and progress=0.5 it would be something close to 180 (going backwards from 0 ... 270 ... 180 ... 90 ... 2)

Comment: I would need to know what the result is for some test examples, just assume your writing some unit tests. You should add it to the question.

Comment: @Surt i have added some examples that hopefully clarifies the behaviour.

Comment: Under the usual math convention, angles increase in the counter-clockwise direction, so your examples are incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the usual convention (angles increase in the counter-clockwise direction), here is a PHP solution.

`$from` and `$to` are normalized angles (between 0 and 360).
`$cw` is a boolean (`true` for clockwise, `false` for counter-clockwise).
`$progress` is between 0 and 1.

```php
function angle_lerp($from, $to, $cw, $progress)
{
    if($cw)
    {
        // Clockwise
        if($from < $to)
            $to -= 360;
    }
    else
    {
        // Counter-clockwise
        if($from > $to)
            $to += 360;
    }
    return $from + ($to-$from)*$progress;
}
```

Examples:

```php
echo angle_lerp(350, 10, true, 0.5); // 180
echo angle_lerp(350, 10, false, 0.5); // 360
```

Comment: pretty sure this solution can return negative angles.

Comment: @maniek So? I didn't say that the function was returning a normalized angle. Just that it takes normalized angles as input.

Comment: thanks exactly what is was looking for :)